# “COPY” statement with “REPLACING” in COBOL

Tags: cobol

can i use replacing clause and let below codes 
base on IBM cobol
fieldcpy:

`01 field-define
    03 :aaa:-field-1
    03 :aaa:-field-2`

i'd like to remove the prefix of **:aaa:-** and have  this:

`01 field-define
    03 field-1
    03 field-2`

i tried below statement but it does work:

`copy fieldcopy
    replacing ==:aaa:-== with " ".`

it seems i have 2 problems:

1. replacing clause does not identify the "-" of **:aaa:-**
2. by clause does not accept null value or space value

similar question i found :
http://computer-programming-forum.com/48-cobol/2cd93fd177e39127.htm

but the advise of below does work.

`COPY SBKACDET REPLACING ==(PR)-== BY ==''==.`

Comment: Did you try changing `:aaa:-` to `:aaa-:` ?

Comment: Why are replacing it with spaces? those tags a usually used to replace with something meaningful

Comment: i have some Cobol codes generated by program. but i don't have source of generator. if i can remove the prefix of variable, the generated codes could work.

Comment: @ZhongYu
Did the provided answer "worked for you"? If yes: please accept as working answer, if there's something unclear add this in its comment and I'll try to add the missing bits. stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really wanted was something like this: (syntax is from memory, I hope I got it right):

```
01 :aaa:-define.
    03 :aaa:-1 pic x(1).
    03 :aaa:-2 pic x(1).
```

Then copy it like this:

```
copy "FILENAME"
    replacing ==:aaa:== with ==field==.
copy "FILENAME"
    replacing ==:aaa:== with ==second==.
```

To get this:

```
01 field-define.
    03  field-1 pic x(1).
    03  field-2 pic x(1).
01 second-define.
    03  second-1 pic x(1).
    03  second-2 pic x(1).
```

Comment: thanks, but not i want. it's to remove the prefix of variable. your syntax is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: According to IBM docs it should work. But you need to use correct syntax that replaces *partial-words*:

```
copy fieldcopy
   replacing leading ==:aaa:-== by == ==.
```